# Does one keep its ivp6 address on different networks?

Tags: ipv6

Assuming I connect on a ipv6 network in Europe and do the same later in the US, I won't keep the ipv6 I was assigned in Europe for use in the US correct?

One will be assigned a new ipv6 address at each connection or am I getting this wrong?

Is there any such think as fix/static addresses for devices in ipv6 (something like public ipv4 addresses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you receive your assignment directly from an Regional Internet Registry, or if you got it from your ISP.

ISPs very rarely allow you to transfer their address space to another provider... assuming you kept the same provider in the US and Europe, this might not be an issue if they are willing to transfer the subnet.

Since you're asking here, I assume you got it directly from an RIR... if that is the case, it now belongs to you... announce it from wherever you like.

This said, help me understand why you ask... can you use DNS to solve changing addresses of hosts?

Comment: Well, I am working on P2P systems and in ipv4, it is easy to make the difference between public and private address. But, you should always anticipate that a given peer may be assigned a different address over time. From your answer: its the same for ipv6. That's the info I was looking for.

Comment: With IPv6 the idea is that every address is routable and there are no private addresses hidden behind NAT

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of DNS.  IPs are allocated in a routable structure, they don't move from place to place.